ML.GENERATE_EMBEDDING expects the 2nd argument to contain a column named content of type STRING
Dears
i'm trying to implement this tutorial
BigQuery vector search and embedding generation
From Google Cloud Tech channel on Youtube.
when i'm trying to execuate this query it's give this error

Invalid table-valued function ML.GENERATE_EMBEDDING
ML.GENERATE_EMBEDDING expects the 2nd argument to contain a column
named content of type STRING. at [2:8]

this is the query
create or replace table `my_project_ID.my_dataset_ID.image_embeddings` as (
  select *,
  regexp_extract(uri,r'[^/]+$') as obj_name,
  regexp_replace(regexp_extract(uri,r'[^/]+$'),r'\.jpg$','') as sku_id,
  '' as prodect_name
  from ML.GENERATE_EMBEDDING(
    MODEL `my_project_ID.my_dataset_ID.embedding_model`,
    TABLE `my_dataset_ID.image_object_table`
     
  )
);

image_object_table is object table generated using this query
create or replace external table `my_project_ID.my_dataset_ID.image_object_table`
with connection `my_connection_ID`
options (
  object_metadata = 'SIMPLE',
  uris = [
    'gs://my_images_bucket_ID/*'
  ]
);

this is the schema for image_object_table
Field name Type Mode Description
uri STRING  NULLABLE    
generation  INTEGER NULLABLE    
content_type    STRING  NULLABLE
size    INTEGER NULLABLE
md5_hash    STRING  NULLABLE
updated TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
metadata    RECORD  REPEATED


Hi @user3106820, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

i think this feature still on preview stage
link

For the table use a select statement the content_type field should be changed to content.
create or replace table project.dataset.table_for_embedding as (
  SELECT *
FROM ML.GENERATE_EMBEDDING(
  MODEL `project.dataset.model`,
   (select *, content_type as content from`project.dataset.object_table`))
);

You might want to except the content_type field if you want to.
